How to using shader processing in flutter without image decoding and copy?
I'm aiming to implement a video playback feature that displays a video with a transparent background. The video consists of two parts: one video stream contains the normal video content, and the other provides a monochrome mask video to achieve transparency.
Currently, I'm using the AlphaPlayer library, which works well but is implemented natively and only supports Android and iOS.
I'm seeking a cross-platform solution to enable this feature on Android, iOS, OpenHarmony OS, and web.
I tried the RenderProxyBox solution similar to the one in animated_sampler with a fragment shader like this one pixelation fragment shader. It worked, but this solution decodes every picture and feeds it to the shader for processing. Due to high-resolution pictures (the video is full screen), the decoding and memory footprint are too large for phones to handle, even with a 15fps video.
After some optimization (reducing video size and fps), I decided to explore alternative solutions to avoid the memory-intensive copying process. However, I haven't found a way to directly bind a texture ID to a FragmentProgram.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.
